# php class call function within function

Tags: php, class

Could someone help me understand how I can make functions within class methods, that would allow me to do things like this:

`$class->send->activation_email()`

I've seen many APIs do this, so I've tried:

```
class MyClass 
{

    public function send()
    {

        function activation_email()
        {
            echo "success!";
        }

    }
}


Undefined property: MyClass::$send
```

Comment: In the example `$class->send->activation_email()` "send" is also a (instance of a) class not a function. If it was a function, it would be `$class->send()->activation_email()`, and it would have to be a function that returned an instance of a class that had a activation_email method in it.

Comment: Whoever just deleted their answer, i think it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone had answered but deleted the post. This is along the lines of what I was hoping for, and it works as expected:

```
class MyClass {

    public function send(){
        echo "Sending: ";
        return $this;
    }

    public function activation_email(){
        echo "activation email.";
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->send()->activation_email();
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

```
class emailSender()
{
   function activation_email()
   {
      if (mail($this->to, $this->subj, $this->body)) {
          print $this->msg;
      }
}

class MyClass 
{
 var $send;
 function __construct()
 {
    $this->send=new emailSender();
    $this->send->msg="success!";
  }
}

$obj=new MyClass();
$obj->send->activation_email();
```

Comment: Ah, so really that first method is just a declaration of a separate class, and the function called is within that second class. ... interesting...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to an instance of another class within your class. Make a variable inside your class like this:

```
$this->otherclass = new Otherclass();
```

In this case, you can call functions from your other class the following way:

```
$myClass->otherclass->otherClassFunction()
```

Answer (score -2):

What you are referring to (shame on no one for noticing this, for shame) is called "method chaining".  A lot of big frameworks do this.  Consider this example of use:

```
echo $obj->setName('Mike')->convertMtoN()->getName();
//  Echoes "Nike"
```

Cool.

But here is how it works:

```
class Example {

    private $name = '';

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        //  We return the object, so you can call it again.
        return $this;
    }

    public function convertMtoN() {

        // Let's do Caps first
        $this->name = str_replace("M", "N", $this->name);

        // Then lowercase
        $this->name = str_replace("m", "n", $this->name);

        // We return the object, keep working
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$name = new Example;

echo $name->setName('Mike')->convertMtoN()->getName();
```

Essentially, for each method that does not implicitly return a value, you simply return the object, allowing you to continue chaining.

Awesome, right?

PHP rocks (now, I know it has its faults, but with HHVM and process forking, it basically rocks [dude, you will get there]).

You can play with this here:
https://ideone.com/fMcQ9u

Comment: Wait, what?  What's not a method?

Comment: I am talking about the question. Not sure what you responded to?

Comment: Funny, because the OP clearly didn't understand the usage correctly and even answered them-self with the same answer I gave (admittedly, I didn't notice and answered anyway).  Sooooo, while you are trying to be oh soooo cool and funny, this is actually the solution to the problem the OP was posing.  Weeeiiiirrddddd.

Comment: This site is note a personal help forum for OP. So while this *might* possibly answer OP all other future readers are utterly confused while your keyboard has apparently some sticky keys.

Comment: Popular request: curb your enthusiasm, focus on accuracy.

Comment: The OP posed a queston in a reasonable yet confused manner.  It stands to reason that future explorers will be in the same situation.  What they will see is a helpful answer to a question they did not fully understand.  Then, just below it, after have found their solution, they will see someone making an irrelevant symantical joke (you, being an idiot) having a fruitless argument with the person who just helped them.  You have made your mark...  You have made your mark...

Comment: @Chris, I do get that, but can we really have this argument when the OP even admitted his mistake?  If  you would like, make a suggested edit to the OP's question.  Otherwise..  I think w are really done...

Comment: What is so great about HHVM?

Comment: HHVM enforces (but does not require) strict type-checking in method parameters, as well as return values all the way down to scalars, optimizes the op-codes and caches php at the machine level, and enforces typed arrays/collections and offers immutable object properties.  Just to name some.  On one hand, if those things don't matter to you, then HHVM is not for you.  If they do matter to you, you will know what those things mean, and you'll understand how those features bring PHP ever so closer to being on par with many compiled languages and environments in terms of performance and stability.

Comment: @MichaelJMulligan I think you should seriously consider modifying your tone. One could examine the credibility of the people you're interacting with here, and possibly summon up a little embarrassment. I'm embarrassed on your behalf. PeeHaa knows what HHVM is, and I assure you he understands it quite well. I would hazard that he understands it better than you. I would also spare the lectures and walk away. Your call.

Comment: I'd just like to add to what Chris said, and note that unlike PeeHaa, @ircmaxell is a complete PHP noob with no php experience whatsoever. Also, you should consider _why_ you're getting that feedback.

Comment: I get those things, am not embarrassed, am sure PeeHaa knows about HHVM and many things.  Rep does/doesn't mean things, I get that as well.  "Except that it doesn't" - Thanks, that's cool, could you elaborate?  I've looked introspectively, and I get my tone is a bit off, but (if some one could revive it) PeeHaa's first note, coupled with the fact that the answer I posed was precisely (admittedly) the answer the OP was looking for: no, I don't see why I'm getting the feedback I am.  This Question (+ feedback), my tone, and HHVM are all separate matters.  However, I'm done here, see you in chat?

Comment: For future explorers: I'm simply not sure myself and the above commenters are on the same page, although I imagine we all mean well, are likely generally adept in our fields, and are driving for the same general goals. It just seems there has been some form of breakdown and illustration as to why public forums are a difficult place to have one on one discussions. Please forgive us for making a mess. Cheers.